# JSON data not being saved in WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm following a Pluralsight course on AngularJS and WebAPI together. I'm trying to save data being sent from the client to the server using `PUT`, but the data is not saving and I'm not getting any errors. Also, It doesn't event hit the correct server side code because the breakpoints are not being caught. I've tried to change the type of `HTTP` method, but I need this one. The only thing being sent back is a `"204: No Content"` code from the server.

This is how the `PUT` and `POST` methods look like. Breakpoints in any of these methods will not be captured.

```
// POST: api/Products
public void Post([FromBody]Product product) // Creating a product
{
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var newProduct = productRepository.Save(product);
}
// PUT: api/Products/5
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Product product) // Updating a product
{
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var updatedProduct = productRepository.Save(id, product);
}
```

`ProductRepository` looks like this:

```
internal Product Save(Product product)
{
    // Read in the existing products
    var products = this.Retrieve();
    // Assign a new Id
    var maxId = products.Max(p => p.ProductID);

    product.ProductID = maxId + 1;
    products.Add(product);

    WriteData(products);

    return product;
}

internal Product Save(int id, Product product)
{
    // Read in the existing products
    var products = this.Retrieve();

    // Locate and replace the item
    var itemIndex = products.FindIndex(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID);
    if (itemIndex > 0)
    {
        products[itemIndex] = product;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

    WriteData(products);
    return product;
}
```

This is the main part of the controller that is being used (using `Controller-As syntax`:

```
var vm = this;
vm.submit = function () {
    vm.message = "";
    if (vm.product.productID) {
        vm.product.$update({ id: vm.product.productID }, function (data { 
            console.log(data);
            vm.message = "Save Complete";
        });
    } else {
        vm.product.$save(function (data) {
            vm.originalProduct = angular.copy(data);
            vm.message = "Save Complete";
        });
    }
};
```

Finally, productResource is a custom service that looks like this:

```
var productResource = function($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Products/:id", null, {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' }
    });
}
```

I've tried to look to see if it's a `CORS` problem, but it's not since I have it enabled at the class level.

Comment: Your post and put Web API methods don't appear to return anything.  I think they should be returning a response?

Comment: @ChrisNevill The `204: No Content` is the default response I guess, but they don't need to return a custom response in order to save the data. Which is what the problem is.

Comment: Strange the debuggers not hitting your breakpoints.  You sure the clients connecting to the right server, not IIS when you're debugging in IIS express or something like that?  I use breakpoints with Web API all the time and they do work.

Comment: @ChrisNevill Client using the right server. I've had no issues with breakpoints not being hit. Well up until now.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your API if it implements CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)

Comment: It's enabled at the class level.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
var itemIndex = products.FindIndex(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID);
```

be

```
var itemIndex = products.FindIndex(p => p.ProductID == id);
```

Comment: What about your routing in `global.asax.cs`, can you show that? Since you are saying the code isn't even hitting the break point.